# Bounded fluid "repel" formula/simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations

I'm attempting to simulate a simple fluid dynamic where there is a "compression" (like a finger pressing down at the origin, causing the liquid to expel outwards) or a "repelling force" at the origin, causing all the particles of the fluid to expel outwards. Something like this:

[image]

This is the best image I can find on the net, the image does not accurately represent what I'm trying to simulate, but it gives an idea.

The area is bounded, so the fluid cannot go past a certain distance from the origin.

Is there a formula where I can find the density at any point a specific distance from the origin? I expect density will change because of the repelling force at the origin.

Assuming particles are evenly spaced at the start, can I determine the position of each particle after I apply the force at the origin?

If two dimensions is difficult, what about modelling the particles in one dimension?

Comment: It may be easier to help if you specify the dependence of the force on r, and also the compressibility of the fluid.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to fluid dynamics. I'm assuming just water for the fluid? So imcompressible? My goal is to actually create an animation where user presses on the touchscreen and it pushes particles away in a physically satisfying way